# Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent - Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sknode

Ok. this code is driving me crazy. It just don't work. The only message I received is "Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent". Yes I know that there has been some discussions here, but none of them give the solution I need.

This is the code. I really appreciate any help.

```
import SpriteKit

class MyScene: SKScene {

  let intervalShapeCreation:NSTimeInterval = 2.0  // Interval for creating the next Shape
  let gravitationalAcceleration:CGFloat = -0.5    // The gravitational Y acceleration

  let shapeSequenceAction = SKAction.sequence([
    SKAction.scaleTo(1.0, duration: 0.5),
    SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0),
    SKAction.scaleTo(0, duration: 0.5),
    SKAction.removeFromParent()
    ])

  override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)
  }

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    super.didMoveToView(view)
    addBackground()
    initializeScene()
  }

  // MARK: Level Building
  func initializeScene() {
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, gravitationalAcceleration)
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
      SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(self.createShape),
      SKAction.waitForDuration(intervalShapeCreation)])))
  }

  func addBackground() {
    let backgroundAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "background")
    let background = SKSpriteNode(texture: backgroundAtlas.textureNamed("background"))
    background.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
    background.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    background.zPosition = -1
    background.name = "background"
    self.addChild(background)
  }

  func createShape() {
    let newShape = sSharedAllPossibleShapes[0]
    print("\n shape creada: \(newShape.name)")
    newShape.position = CGPointMake(size.width / 2, CGFloat( Int.random(fromZeroToMax: 500)))
    self.addChild(newShape)
    newShape.runAction(shapeSequenceAction)
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you expound on "doesn't work"? Please try to articulate what the expected behavior is.

Comment: Ok. What it must do is to show some Shapes all around the screen in the same x-position and random y-position. This shapes must last for 2 seconds and then disappeared and removed. It can create the first one without problems, but the rest stop with the same inconvenient of "Attempted to add a SKNode which already has a parent".

Answer (score 1):

createShape doesn't actually create a SKShapeNode. It gets the first shape from the sSharedAllPossibleShapes array, then adds it as child to self. The second time you call this method that shape already has a parent and can't be added again.

You have to create a new instance of SKShapeNode. The way I see it your array here really needs to contain the CGPath objects that define the shape, not the nodes themselves because you can't reuse nodes the way you intended to.

Comment: Ok. sSharedAllPossibleShapes is an array that contains all possible shapes to use in the game. Every shape is a subclass of SKSpriteNode and what I want it was to avoid create the same possible shapes every time and instead take them from an array pull. Is this not possible? If not, can you suggest me the code? I really don't understand what is the CGPath you mention.

Comment: Then you'll want to create multiple shapes using the same texture. Identical textures are shared between sprite instances.